# Is there a way to use the queries developed within Python in django

Tags: python, django

I have developed many SQLite queries using python (see an example here below) and I'd like to publish the results of the query via Django web page.

I have installed Django and created the ORM linked to the SQLITEDB.

My question: is there a way to call these queries (created with Python) or their results directly from Django? Or I have to recode these queries into "Django" language?

I have already started recording these queries in a compatible 'Django language"  under views.py and an HTML page. I'm afraid that I'm losing my time in recoding. Any recommendations or advice that can help are welcome.

Example of a query in Python :

```
cursor.execute(""" SELECT  "AgentName", count (*) FROM "CSQ Agent Report" WHERE  "AgentName" != "None"  
AND "OriginatorDNHANDELED" = '1' or "OriginatorDNNOTHANDELED" = '1' Group by "AgentName"  """)

liste8 = cursor.fetchall()

for i in range (len(liste8)):
    
    print (liste8[i][0],liste8[i][1])
```

Here below what I started coding in Django views and HTML page in Django views

```
def home(request):
    
queryset = CsqAgentReport.objects.values('agentname').filter(csqnames__exact = 
'CSQ_HDF*').filter(contactdisposition__contains='2').annotate(total=Count('nodeid_sessionid_sequenceno',distinct=True)).order_by('csqnames')


context = {
        'object_list' : queryset,
           }
```

***In the html file :***

```
{% block content %} 

<h1> Stats Call Center </h1>
<p> Total calls  -- object_list</p>
<ul>
  {% for var_nbr_app_repond in object_list %}
      <li> {{var_nbr_app_repond.total}} appel(s)- {{var_nbr_app_repond.csqnames}}- 
      {{var_nbr_app_repond.agentname }}-{{var_nbr_app_repond.talktime }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries you really should know what you are doing in sql if you use this. If you open your server to the public and your statments dont escape properly, you can get big problems.

Comment: These queries are for internal purposes . Not for public web site , just aN intranet for a limited group .

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about executing SQL in Django, just do it :-)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: It is not anly about executing SQL  but also hiw to render the data into web format .